# Adding Hidden Value On UL and LI Tags, How?

Tags: php, arrays, hidden

I have multiple options like this :

```
<li>
<a href="#" title="" class="selected"><span class="to-admin">Administrator</span></a>
<input id="shareto" type="hidden" value="0-1" name="shareto">
</li>
<li>
<a href="#" title=""><span class="to-finance">Finance</span></a>
<input id="shareto" type="hidden" value="1-1" name="shareto">
</li>
<li>
<a href="#" title=""><span class="to-technician">Technician</span></a>
<input id="shareto" type="hidden" value="1-0" name="shareto">
</li>
<li>
<a href="#" title=""><span class="to-lawyer">Legal</span></a>
<input id="shareto" type="hidden" value="0-0" name="shareto">
</li>
```

and now I want to 'catch' that variable using this PHP :

```
$Type = $_POST['shareto'];
```

why I always get the last value, no matter what option I choose? how to do it correctly? thanks before.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? And you're getting only 1 value because you have same names for all inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check this working fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/7GHug/

I think you want something like this.

```
<ul>
<li data-val="0-1">
<a href="#" title="" class="selected"><span class="to-admin">Administrator</span></a>

</li>
<li data-val="1-1">
<a href="#" title=""><span class="to-finance">Finance</span></a>

</li>
<li data-val="1-0">
<a href="#" title=""><span class="to-technician">Technician</span></a>
</li>
<li data-val="0-0">
<a href="#" title=""><span class="to-lawyer">Legal</span></a>
<input id="shareto" type="hidden" value="" name="shareto">
</li>
</ul>​
```

Javascritp

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
        $('ul li').on('click', function() {
            $('input#shareto').val($(this).data('val'));
        });
    });
```

With single hidden input you can update the value based on the clicked li.
​

Comment: thanks for the fiddle, Vins. I forgot to tell you that those UL and LI tags is under FORM tag. means I have SUBMIT button on the bottom. do I have to modify your Javascript? because my PHP still get empty value after I click submit button.

Comment: Okay as you've mentioned in the above comments. How i'll come to know which li is selected initially. If you know the initial li which is selected then just put value of it in the input as I've kept it as blank. I think this should do.

Comment: you mean adding initial selected value to this : <input id="shareto" type="hidden" value="" name="shareto"> ? I tried to put '0-1' as initial value of Administrator : <input id="shareto" type="hidden" value="0-1" name="shareto"> but no matter what option I choose, the value still 0-1. can't change into 0-0 when I choose Legal (for example).

Comment: If you implemented my code then it will put that value. Check the fiddle link I'll make it text instead of hidden. http://jsfiddle.net/7GHug/1/ Check this.

Comment: Vins, something odd happens here... I copied and pasted your Fiddle here : http://roberthanson.net/index.html but still the value doesn't change just like on Fiddle. what's wrong with it?

Comment: Check the version of jQuery Please use the latest one. As I'm using .on method which is introduced in 1.7 please change your jquery or change .on to old click method.

Comment: Please try this. http://jsfiddle.net/7GHug/2/ I've changed fiddle to 1.6.4 and modified my code.

Answer (score 3):

If you change `name=shareto` to `name=shareto[]` then `$_POST['shareto'];` will be an array containing all the values.

Also element `id`s should be unique.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I did just like what you said. but when I put this code on my PHP : print_r ($Type); I get all array content. how to get array value associated with option selected? thanks.

Comment: @RobertHanson So you want a specific value? Based on what criteria?

Comment: based on selected LI. for example, if I choose 'FINANCE', the $Type value will be '1-1'

Comment: If its based on clicking the li, then Vins answer would be what you want

Answer (score 2):

```
Add [] like name="shareto[]" then $Type = implode(',',$_POST['shareto']);
```